# Ionic toggle group check one item and uncheck the others

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have created a toggle view to select available items in Ionic, and if anyone of the item were selected, I want to uncheck all the other items. I also have a scan function which allows me to dynamically update the items list

I'm fairly new to ionic, so I just have the following code in my `settings.html`

```
<ion-toggle ng-repeat="item in itemsList"
         ng-model="item.checked">
    {{ item.text }}
</ion-toggle>
```

and then I have created a simple `settings.js`:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('i18n.setting').controller('Settings', Settings);
    SettingController.$inject = ['$scope'];

    function Settings($scope){
        $scope.settingsList = [
            {text: "item1", checked: true},
            {text: "item2", checked: false}
        ];
    }
})();
```

I know `ng-model="item.checked"` will do the job of changing the attribute `$scope.settingsList.checked` for me. But what I want to know this how to use it to check one items and uncheck all the other ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

loop through all the items, set the checked state of all the values to false and then your html code must be:

```
<ion-toggle ng-repeat="item in settingsList"
                ng-model="item.checked" 
                ng-checked="item.checked" style="border:1px solid #28a54c" ng-change="toggleChange(item)">
      {{ item.text }}
</ion-toggle>
```

Your Controller code

```
$scope.toggleChange = function(item) {
      if (item.checked == true) {
          for(var index = 0; index < $scope.settingsList.length; ++index)
              $scope.settingsList[index].checked = false;
          item.checked = true;
      } else {
        item.checked = false
      }
};
```

And it's better to use `forEach` in async environment.

Comment: Yep, I originally used double nested for loops to solve this problem, but your solution is cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

**Angular 2+ Version, Ionic 4**

HTML

```
<div class="toogle" *ngFor="let item of toogleConfig">
  <div class="toogle__title">{{item.title}}</div>
    <ion-toggle [(ngModel)]="item.checked" (ngModelChange)="ToogleChange(item.id)" color="success"></ion-toggle>
  </div> 
</div>
```

TS

```
public toogleConfig = [
    {id:0, title:'Recurrent', checked: false},
    {id:1, title:'One time', checked: false},
  ]

public ToogleChange(index:number) {        
    this.toogleConfig.forEach(toogle => { toogle.checked = false; });
    this.toogleConfig[index].checked = true;
  }
```