# uncheck toggle angular won't work

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, toggle

I don't like that answer because of this:

> Note that this directive should not be used together with ngModel, as this can lead to unexpected behavior.

### Also, I'm not using ng-repeat at all. IMO it's not a dupe.

I have 3 ionic toggles. When I check one of them I want to uncheck the other two.
For some reason it's not working. Ignore the inline css.

```
<div class="list">
    <ion-toggle ng-model="production" toggle-class="toggle toggle-big" ng-checked=" !washingup || !dispensing""> <img src="img/production5.png" height="50" width="50" align="left" /><p style="padding-top: 14px; padding-left: 8px;">Production</p>
    </ion-toggle>         
    <ion-toggle ng-model="dispensing" toggle-class="toggle toggle-big" ng-checked=" !washingup || !production"> <img src="img/dispensing1.png" height="50" width="50" align="left" /><p style="padding-top: 14px; padding-left: 8px;">Dispensing</p>
    </ion-toggle>       
    <ion-toggle ng-model="washingup" toggle-class="toggle toggle-big" ng-checked=" !production || !dispensing"> <img src="img/washingUp1.png" height="50" width="50" align="left" /><p style="padding-top: 14px; padding-left: 8px;">Washing up</p>
    </ion-toggle>
</div>
```

Comment: How about https://stackoverflow.com/a/39166231/8317956?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ionic toggle group check one item and uncheck the others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38924681/ionic-toggle-group-check-one-item-and-uncheck-the-others)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I don't like the solution mentioned in [Ionic toggle group check one item and uncheck the others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38924681/ionic-toggle-group-check-one-item-and-uncheck-the-others/39166231#39166231). For some reason there is [`ngModel`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) together with [`ngChecked`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked) in the markup, but as described in the docs:

> Note that this directive should not be used together with ngModel, as
>   this can lead to unexpected behavior.

For this particular question removing [`ngChecked`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked) and simply using [`ngChange`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) with inline expression could do the trick:

```
<div class="list">
    <ion-toggle ng-model="production" toggle-class="toggle toggle-big" 
        ng-change="production && (dispensing = washingup = false)"> 
        <img src="img/production5.png" height="50" width="50" align="left" />
        <p style="padding-top: 14px; padding-left: 8px;">Production</p>
    </ion-toggle>         
    <ion-toggle ng-model="dispensing" toggle-class="toggle toggle-big" 
        ng-change="dispensing && (production = washingup = false)"> 
        <img src="img/dispensing1.png" height="50" width="50" align="left" />
        <p style="padding-top: 14px; padding-left: 8px;">Dispensing</p>
    </ion-toggle>       
    <ion-toggle ng-model="washingup" toggle-class="toggle toggle-big" 
        ng-change="washingup && (dispensing = production = false)"> 
        <img src="img/washingUp1.png" height="50" width="50" align="left" />
        <p style="padding-top: 14px; padding-left: 8px;">Washing up</p>
    </ion-toggle>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved my issue, Still learning angular so far. Had no idea I could do this for example: dispensing && (production = washingup = false)